# Dynamically modify layout from within onItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, class, layout, dynamic

i'm having a problem while i dynamically try to change the layout when a spinner is changed.
I need to find the main view from within the onItemSelectedListener method.
Here the code

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        if (parent.getSelectedItemPosition()==0){//Apertura di un libro

            LinearLayout lyt_libro = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            lyt_libro.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            //HERE THE PROBLEM. HOW CAN I FIND THE MAIN LAYOUT IN WHICH I CAN ADD THE lyt_libro?
            final EditText etx_numeroPagine = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            lyt_libro.addView(etx_numeroPagine);
            [... other stuff....]
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ScrollView view_mainScroll = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout lyt_main = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    view_mainScroll.addView(lyt_main);
    lyt_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    final Spinner spn_selectInterrogationType = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
    lyt_main.addView(spn_selectInterrogationType);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> spn_selectInterrItemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spn_selectInterrItemAdapter.add("Apertura di un libro");
    spn_selectInterrItemAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spn_selectInterrogationType.setAdapter(spn_selectInterrItemAdapter);
    spn_selectInterrogationType.setPrompt("Tipo di metodo utilizzato");

    spn_selectInterrogationType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    setContentView(view_mainScroll);
}
```

I commented where i have the problem.. What can i do to find it? I'm quite new both to java and android, so i'm a bit lost :)
And another doubt i have: is it right to use getApplicationContext()? From what i understood by the api docs, it is better not to use it, but i can't see how to do without it..

Thanks so much!! :D

EDIT:
i'm creating all the layout from code, since i need to change every element dynamically at runtime, so i need to retrieve it with a function or something like.. With xml i have no problems, but they aren't what i need

Answer (score 0):

You can use an identifier in your XML for the main layout, and in your code you can find it by using findViewById(R.id.name_in_your_xmlFile)

Remember also to cast to the view that you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Give a name/id, in your xml file, to the layout that will contain your component .

Then get the layout by using findViewById.

And add your view.

Another technique could be to declare your field in your xml file with attribute visibility gone and, in your code, in response to your event, get the view (by id as above) and setVisilibity to View.VISIBLE.

Regards,
Stéphane